# Electric field in a non-ideal MOSCAP

Tags: mosfet

Consider a MOSCAP with fixed charge \$Q_f\$ per unit area at oxide-semiconductor interface and non-zero difference between work function of metal and semiconductor. The question is to compute the electric field in the oxide at flatband voltage. One way to tackle this problem is use the fact that the gate voltage is the sum of potential drops across metal(which is zero), oxide and semiconductor. Exploiting the fact that at flatband condition potential drop  across semiconductor is zero, we arrive at the formula
$$
E_{ox}=\frac{V_{fb}}{t_{ox}}.
$$
We can also express flat-band voltage as:
$$
V_{fb}=\phi_{ms}-\frac{Q_{f}}{C_{ox}}.
$$ 
Thus after further simplifications we arrive at:
$$
E_{ox}=\frac{\phi_{ms}}{t_{ox}}-\frac{Q_f}{K_{ox}\epsilon_{o}}.
$$
However another approach is to use Gauss law. At flat band condition we have charge density and electric field in semiconductor to be zero. Now by using the Guass law to relate the discontinuity in displacement vector in oxide and semiconductor we arrive at
$$
D_{ox}=Q_f. 
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
E_{ox}=\frac{Q_f}{K_{ox}\epsilon_{o}}.
$$

> Which method is correct and why is the other method wrong?

Comment: One of those methods results in an equation that is the answer to the question and one does not. But other than that, why do you think one is wrong? Those are not obviously contradictory equations.

Comment: @Matt The use of second method yields a different expression for electric field. What is wrong in this method? Is there any additional charge other than Qf at the semiconductor-oxide interface?

Comment: Could you add the second expression for electric field to your question? I only see one.

Comment: @matt /$ E_{ox}=\frac{Q_f}{K_s \epsilon_{o}} /$ results from the second method.

Comment: You should edit that into the question so people dont need to read through the comments. While doing that, put the two equations for electric field in terms of the same variables.

Comment: Ahh. Now I see the problem you are talking about. I hope you now see the benefit of including all your work in the question. I will update my answer in an hour or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation for electric field is incorrect:

$$
E_{ox} = \frac{V_{fb}}{t_{ox}} = \frac{\phi_{ms}}{t_{ox}}-\frac{Q_f}{K_{ox}\epsilon_0}
$$

The electric field is the voltage across the oxide divided by the oxide thickness. \$V_{fb}\$ is not the voltage across the oxide at flatband.

The correct electric field (at flatband) is:

$$
E_{ox}=\frac{Q_f}{K_{ox}\epsilon_0}
$$

To expand upon this, we assume there is no charge in the metal (normal assumption for a metal) or oxide (there could be, but there isn't in this question) and at flatband there is no charge in the semiconductor (by definition). The only place there can be charge in this structure is at the metal-oxide and metal-semiconductor junctions. Charge can move to the metal-oxide junction freely, but there are limitations on the oxide-semiconductor junction. In order to put charge at this junction you either need interface charge, which we know to be \$Q_f\$, or you have to put the semiconductor into accumulation or depletion mode. But we are at flatband, so we aren't in accumulation or depletion. Therefore, there is no additional charge at the oxide-semiconductor interface, meaning the voltage across the oxide is not a function of \$\phi_{ms}\$ but only a function of \$Q_f\$. From this you can integrate the charge to get electric field, which is therefore only a function of \$Q_f\$.

Comment: I did not understand why the voltage across the oxide isn't $ V_{fb} $.  At flat band condition the applied potential must drop across oxide layer (which is $ V_{fb} $)

Comment: @InderjeetNair I added an explanation to my answer. Hopefully this helps.